# Paris in Jan Christmas decorations

Tags: paris, sightseeing, christmas

I am travelling to Paris on the 7th of January, 2019. I wanted to know if the Christmas lights and decorations will still be there around the city at that time. It's my first visit to Paris, so that would be a great added attraction.

Answer (score 4):

You can find here https://www.parisinfo.com/decouvrir-paris/les-grands-rendez-vous/noel-a-paris/illuminations-de-noel/les-illuminations-de-noel-a-paris locations and beginning/end date of Christmas decoration in Paris. Even though it's in French I believe it's still understandable.

Notice that most of them will end around your arrival. "Illuminations 2.0 sur le boulevard Haussmann" & "Les vitrines de Noël du Printemps Haussmann" (La Fayette) is the ones I will recommend.

Comment: They have an english page too [here](https://en.parisinfo.com/discovering-paris/major-events/christmas-in-paris/christmas-lights/christmas-lights-in-paris)